# SQL: Select the first value of each category and transform the dataset to show FROM and TO relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, left-join, aggregate

I have a mobile app browsing history dataset as shown below.

- UserID: each UserID represents a visitor who login the mobile app.
- PageName: There are different pages in the Mobile App. All visitors
  would first land on the Home page, and then navigate to different
  pages.
- Sequence: the order of the pages visited. For example, Seq_1 Home >
  Seq_2 My Account = first landing on Home page, then navigate to "My
  Account" page.

| UserID | PageName | PageSequence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| UserA | Home | Seq_1 |
| UserA | My Account | Seq_2 |
| UserA | My Activity | Seq_3 |
| UserA | Restaurant Listing | Seq_4 |
| UserA | Restaurant Details Page | Seq_5 |
| UserA | Restaurant Details Page | Seq_6 |
| UserA | Restaurant Booking Confirmation | Seq_7 |
| UserA | Home | Seq_8 |
| UserA | Write To Us | Seq_9 |
| UserA | Home | Seq_10 |
| UserB | Home | Seq_1 |
| UserB | Restaurant Listing | Seq_2 |
| UserB | Restaurant Listing | Seq_3 |

I need to do the following pre-processing in SQL:

1. For each user, keeping a unique list of PageName. For example, for
   UserA, keeping only "Home" in Seq_1 and ignore the other "Home" in
   Seq_8 and Seq_10; keep only "Restaurant Details Page" in Seq_5 and ignore Seq_6.
2. Summarize the dataset into a table as shown below. I would like to show in the table the "FROM" (source page) and "TO" (Target page). For example, 1 visitor has been through the journey FROM "Home" page to "My Account" page; 2 visitors have been through the journey FROM "Restaurant Listing" page to "Restaurant Details Page".

Result Table:

| FROM | TO | No_of_Users |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Home | My Account | 1 |
| My Account | My Activity | 1 |
| My Activity | Restaurant Listing | 1 |
| Restaurant Listing | Restaurant Details Page | 1 |
| Restaurant Details Page | Restaurant Booking Confirmation | 1 |
| Restaurant Booking Confirmation | Write To Us | 1 |
| Home | Restaurant Listing | 1 |

I have around 600,000 users and a total of 21 unique PageName in the dataset.

I have tried the following script to accomplish Objective (1), but I have no idea how Objective (2) can be accomplished.

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #App
CREATE TABLE #App (
    UserID VARCHAR(100),
    PageName VARCHAR(100),
    PageSequence VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #App VALUES
    ('UserA', 'Home', 'Seq_1'),
    ('UserA', 'My Account', 'Seq_2'),
    ('UserA', 'My Activity', 'Seq_3'),
    ('UserA', 'Restaurant Listing', 'Seq_4'),
    ('UserA', 'Restaurant Details Page', 'Seq_5'),
    ('UserA', 'Restaurant Details Page', 'Seq_6'),
    ('UserA', 'Restaurant Booking Confirmation', 'Seq_7'),
    ('UserA', 'Home', 'Seq_8'),
    ('UserA', 'Write To Use', 'Seq_9'),
    ('UserA', 'Home', 'Seq_10'),
    ('UserB', 'Home', 'Seq_1'),
    ('UserB', 'Restaurant Listing', 'Seq_2'),
    ('UserB', 'Restaurant Listing', 'Seq_3');

WITH summary AS(
    SELECT #App.UserID,
           #App.PageName,
           #App.PageSequence,
           CAST(RIGHT(PageSequence, CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(PageSequence)) - 1) AS int) AS PageSequenceFinal,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY #App.PageName, UserID ORDER BY CAST(RIGHT(PageSequence, CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(PageSequence)) - 1) AS int)) AS rk
    FROM #App)
SELECT s.* FROM summary s
WHERE s.rk = 1
ORDER BY UserID, CAST(RIGHT(PageSequence, CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(PageSequence)) - 1) AS int) ASC
```

Comment: Not able to understand the summary information. What is From and To

Comment: @VenkataramanR My apology for the confusion. I would like to show in the table the "FROM" (source page) and "TO" (Target page). For example, 1 visitor has through the journey FROM "Home" page to "My Account" page.

Comment: @DaleK Sorry for the confusion. I have added my SQL attempt in the post. Thanks!

Comment: Code snippets are only for html/css/javascript, other code should be in code blocks like you had before. But also code questions should contain a full [mre]. [ask]

Comment: @philipxy Sorry I am new to Stack Overflow and still have not figured out how to add a table and my SQL script to the post.

Comment: You can indent code 4 characters between blank lines for a code block--as I said, like you had before. But also read all the edit help. You can also search how to use the site by googling with 'site:' & meta.stackoverflow.com or meta.stackexchange.com. [help] Research how to use google.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Show any parts you can do for a goal in which you are stuck.

Comment: Why has 'Restaurant Listing' -> 'Restaurant Details Page' a count of 2? Only UserA did this in your sample data, so I'd count 1.

Comment: @philipxy Thanks for the advice. The table and SQL script has been fixed and now in the correct format. As per "giving the least code I can give", unfortunately, I am also a beginner in SQL and that's the best I can do at the moment.

Comment: @DaleK Expected table fixed in the right format now, thanks!

Comment: On a side note: Can't you change the `PageSequence` column to int in your table? It will be a nuisance to have to convert this in every query you want to use it.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Sorry about the count of 2. It is a typo and is not fixed. Unfortunately, the PageSequence is originally in the source file and I cannot change it.

Comment: In the source *file*? PageSequence is in a *table*. If you really can't change the table, you may consider writing a view.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes, the mobile app history, which comes with the PageSequence column, is a CSV file I received from the Web Team. I uploaded it to SQL Server and then I do the data preparation there.

Comment: Well, sometimes we have to convert data we import into our database. We wouldn't store 'December 10, 2020' as a string either, but convert it to a proper date of course. And have you told the Web team that their sequence format is unfortunate? Maybe *they* can change it.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thanks! You are my hero! I am still digesting your solution. Unfortunately, it seems that there's nothing much Web Team can do. This is just the tip of the iceberg. I am doing a lot of data-preprocessing with the extremely raw data. Thanks again for your help and advice!

Comment: Haha, as to digesting: It's not so difficult, actually. Think of `with_next` as two separate steps: 1. group by userid, pagename to get their minimum sequence. 2. Iterate through this result grouped/partitioned by user ordered by minimum sequence to get the next_pagename.

Comment: Re simplifying: You still don't need the first table, it is just a possibly wrong version of the code initialization, so drop it, but format the code initialization in columns so it looks like the table it is. If you want it with the introduction, move it there. Also it seems like way more input & output than you need. Same for the output, it is better to give actual output. The editing gridded table format is not appropriate for [mre] i/o.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Philipxy was referring to the previous versions of the post. Thanks to him I have learned how to add a table and SQL script to the post. I think the post should be readable now.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner  I just realized a problem. Some UserID appear multiple times (use the app at different datetime) and hence there are duplicates of PageSequence. In addition, the requirement has changed and "Objective (1): keeping a unique list of PageName" is now cancelled. In fixing the issue, I have added an addition column "DeviceDateTime" to the table and tried to add it to the partition. I also tried to delete the minimum sequence and used just pagesequencefinal after ORDER BY instead, but it doesn't work. =[

Comment: Sounds like a different task then, so why not make this a new request?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner You are right! Let me create a new request now, thanks!

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Here is the new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66472930/sql-use-lead-and-partition-by-to-access-to-the-next-row-following-the-current

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the minimum sequence per user and page is a mere aggregation. To get from one page to the next, use `LEAD`:

```
with seq_fixed as
(
  select
    userid,
    pagename,
    cast(right(pagesequence, charindex('_', reverse(pagesequence)) - 1) as int) as pagesequencefinal
  from app
)
, with_next as
(
  select
    userid,
    pagename,
    lead(pagename) over (partition by userid order by min(pagesequencefinal)) as next_pagename
  from seq_fixed
  group by userid, pagename
)
select pagename, next_pagename, count(*)
from with_next
where next_pagename is not null
group by pagename, next_pagename
order by pagename, next_pagename;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=17f41cda710d8cca3152228d831fe0b5