# SQL: Use LEAD() and PARTITION BY to access to the next row following the current row

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, left-join, aggregate

I have a mobile app browsing history dataset as shown below.

- DeviceDateTime: Date and Time the User views the page in the mobile app.
- UserID: each UserID represents a visitor who login the mobile app.
- PageName: There are different pages in the Mobile App. All visitors
  would first land on the Home page, and then navigate to different
  pages.
- PageSequence: the order of the pages visited. For example, Seq_1 Home >
  Seq_2 My Account = first landing on Home page, then navigate to "My
  Account" page.

| DeviceDateTime | UserID | PageName | PageSequence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-19 16:40:00.000 | UserA | Home | Seq_1 |
| 2021-01-19 16:40:00.000 | UserA | My Account | Seq_2 |
| 2021-01-19 16:40:07.000 | UserA | My Activity | Seq_3 |
| 2021-01-19 16:40:07.000 | UserA | Restaurant Listing | Seq_4 |
| 2021-01-19 16:40:18.000 | UserA | Restaurant Details Page | Seq_5 |
| 2021-01-19 16:40:31.000 | UserA | Restaurant Details Page | Seq_6 |
| 2021-01-19 16:40:31.000 | UserA | Restaurant Booking Confirmation | Seq_7 |
| 2021-01-19 16:40:40.000 | UserA | Home | Seq_8 |
| 2021-01-19 16:40:45.000 | UserA | Write To Us | Seq_9 |
| 2021-01-19 16:40:46.000 | UserA | Home | Seq_10 |
| 2021-01-28 21:11:53.000 | UserB | Home | Seq_1 |
| 2021-01-28 21:12:01.000 | UserB | Restaurant Listing | Seq_2 |
| 2021-01-28 21:13:37.000 | UserB | Restaurant Listing | Seq_3 |
| 2021-02-16 09:43:27.000 | UserA | Home | Seq_1 |
| 2021-02-16 09:43:43.000 | UserA | Write To Us | Seq_2 |
| 2021-02-16 09:44:50.000 | UserA | My Account | Seq_3 |
| 2021-02-16 09:45:03.000 | UserA | My Activity | Seq_4 |

I need to do the following pre-processing in SQL:

1. Summarize the dataset into a table as shown below. I would like to show in the table the "FROM" (source page) and "TO" (Target page). For example, 1 visitor has been through the journey FROM "Home" page to "My Account" page; 2 visitors have been through the journey FROM "Home" page to "Write To Us".
2. When the journey is FROM and TO the same page, do not count the journey. For example, UserA Seq_5 and Seq_6, "FROM Restaurant Details Page" TO "Restaurant Details Page" should not be included.
3. Journey across two different users should not be included. For example, FROM "Restaurant Listing" (UserB Seq_3) TO "Home" (UserA Seq_1) should not be included.

Result Table:

| FROM | TO | No_of_Users |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Home | My Account | 1 |
| My Account | My Activity | 2 |
| My Activity | Restaurant Listing | 1 |
| Restaurant Listing | Restaurant Details Page | 1 |
| Restaurant Details Page | Restaurant Booking Confirmation | 1 |
| Restaurant Booking Confirmation | Home | 1 |
| Home | Write To Us | 2 |
| Write To Us | Home | 1 |
| Home | Restaurant Listing | 1 |
| Home | Restaurant Listing | 1 |
| Write To Us | My Account | 1 |

I have around 600,000 users and a total of 21 unique PageName in the dataset.

I have tried the following script but it didn't work. I failed to capture all the possible journeys in the summary table. For example, FROM "Write To Us" TO "My Account", FROM "Restaurant Booking Confirmation" TO "Home" are all missing in the result.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #App
CREATE TABLE #App (
    DeviceDateTime SMALLDATETIME,
    UserID VARCHAR(100),
    PageName VARCHAR(100),
    PageSequence VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #App VALUES
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:00.000','UserA', 'Home', 'Seq_1'),
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:00.000','UserA', 'My Account', 'Seq_2'),
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:07.000','UserA', 'My Activity', 'Seq_3'),
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:07.000','UserA', 'Restaurant Listing', 'Seq_4'),
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:18.000','UserA', 'Restaurant Details Page', 'Seq_5'),
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:31.000','UserA', 'Restaurant Details Page', 'Seq_6'),
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:31.000','UserA', 'Restaurant Booking Confirmation', 'Seq_7'),
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:40.000','UserA', 'Home', 'Seq_8'),
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:45.000','UserA', 'Write To Use', 'Seq_9'),
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:46.000','UserA', 'Home', 'Seq_10'),
    ('2021-01-28 21:11:53.000','UserB', 'Home', 'Seq_1'),
    ('2021-01-28 21:12:01.000','UserB', 'Restaurant Listing', 'Seq_2'),
    ('2021-01-28 21:13:37.000','UserB', 'Restaurant Listing', 'Seq_3'),
    ('2021-02-16 09:43:27.000','UserA', 'Home', 'Seq_1'),
    ('2021-02-16 09:43:43.000','UserA', 'Write To Us', 'Seq_2'),
    ('2021-02-16 09:44:50.000','UserA', 'My Account', 'Seq_3'),
    ('2021-02-16 09:45:03.000','UserA', 'My Activity', 'Seq_4');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #SD
with seq_fixed as
(
  select
    UserID,
    DeviceDateTime,
    PageName,
    cast(right(PageSequence, charindex('_', reverse(PageSequence)) - 1) as int) as pagesequencefinal
  from #App
)
, with_next as
(
  select
    UserID,
    DeviceDateTime,
    PageName,
    lead(PageName) over (partition by UserID, DeviceDateTime order by UserID, DeviceDateTime ASC) as next_pagename
  from seq_fixed
  group by UserID, DeviceDateTime, PageName
)
select PageName, next_pagename, count(*) AS No_of_User
into #SD
from with_next
where next_pagename is not null
group by PageName, next_pagename
order by PageName, next_pagename;

SELECT * FROM #SD
```

Comment: *"it didn't work"* Why didn't it work? Did it error, give unexpected results, undesired behaviour, something else? What are you *actually* asking here; you've dumped a lot of code, data and text on us here but I can't see a clear problem statement (apart from "it didn't work", which tells us nothing) and question. Is it purely that your statement with your CTE failed as you didn't correctly terminate all your statements?

Comment: @Larnu My apology for the confusion. I managed to get a very close result, but I fail to capture all the possible journeys in the summary table. For example, FROM "Write To Us" TO "My Account", FROM "Restaurant Booking Confirmation" TO "Home" are all missing in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your previous request you wanted to only acknowledge a page's first ocurrence per user,
so Home->PageX->Home->PageY would be interpreted as Home->PageX->PageY. For this to happen you had to group by user and page to find this first occurrence.

This is not the case in this new request, so don't aggregate:

```
with seq_fixed as
(
  select
    userid,
    pagename,
    cast(right(pagesequence, charindex('_', reverse(pagesequence)) - 1) as int) as pagesequencefinal
  from app
)
, with_next as
(
  select
    userid,
    pagename,
    lead(pagename) over (partition by userid order by pagesequencefinal) as next_pagename
  from seq_fixed
)
select pagename, next_pagename, count(*)
from with_next
where next_pagename is not null
group by pagename, next_pagename
order by pagename, next_pagename;
```

The only problem with this: When a user ended on PageX yesterday and starts with Home today, this will count as PageX->Home. If you want to prevent this from happening you need some detection for this situation, e.g. don't consider an entry a page change when it's pedecessor is at least 1 hour old or the like. For this you can use your timestamp column and `LAG`.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten, let me do some research on the LAG function and get back to you soon!

Comment: Hi Thorsten, I took your advice and try to solve the "yesterday-today" problem with the lag and timestamp function. It seems that I managed to solve it, but my script is super long. I post my solution as one of the answers in this post. Any chance I can simply the script?

Comment: If you extend my `with_next` to select `DeviceDateTime` and `LAG(DeviceDateTime) OVER (partition by userid order by pagesequencefinal)`, you can extend the main query's `WHERE` clause to only consider rows with a gap of less than, say, 1 hour.

Answer (score 2):

Don't PARTITION BY the `devicedatetime`, ORDER BY it

```
select
    UserID,
    DeviceDateTime,
    PageName,
    lead(PageName) over (partition by UserID order by DeviceDateTime) as next_pagename
  from seq_fixed
```

You shouldn't partition by the time because the partition is "what makes all the rows be considered as belonging to the same set" i.e. the userid being the same is "a set of rows" that are ordered by the time (or sequence). If you divide the rows into sets of "per user per second" you aren't getting a "per user" journey of "one user visited ten pages" you're getting "ten usertimes visited one page"

Also, don't use GROUP BY to squish "navs to the same page", use `... from with_next WHERE next_pagename <> pagename`

You calculate `pageseq` but never use it - either order by it in your LEAD (if you think two datetimes for different pages for the same user will be identical at a per-second precision) or dump it

And finally, if "count of user" is supposed to be "the number of distinct users who have navigated from this page to that page" it needs to be `count(distinct userid) AS No_of_User`, not `count(*)` - countstar is the "number of times this page navigation has occurred, including multiples by the same user". It could perhaps be handy to include both stats, to get an idea of how many users go round and round

Edit:

Here's the modified version of your query with commented out all the bits I recommend removing:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #App;
CREATE TABLE #App (
    DeviceDateTime SMALLDATETIME,
    UserID VARCHAR(100),
    PageName VARCHAR(100),
    PageSequence VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #App VALUES
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:00.000','UserA', 'Home', 'Seq_1'),
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:00.000','UserA', 'My Account', 'Seq_2'),
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:07.000','UserA', 'My Activity', 'Seq_3'),
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:07.000','UserA', 'Restaurant Listing', 'Seq_4'),
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:18.000','UserA', 'Restaurant Details Page', 'Seq_5'),
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:31.000','UserA', 'Restaurant Details Page', 'Seq_6'),
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:31.000','UserA', 'Restaurant Booking Confirmation', 'Seq_7'),
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:40.000','UserA', 'Home', 'Seq_8'),
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:45.000','UserA', 'Write To Use', 'Seq_9'), --TYPO ALERT!!!--TYPO ALERT!!!--TYPO ALERT!!!--TYPO ALERT!!!--TYPO ALERT!!!--TYPO ALERT!!!
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:46.000','UserA', 'Home', 'Seq_10'),
    ('2021-01-28 21:11:53.000','UserB', 'Home', 'Seq_1'),
    ('2021-01-28 21:12:01.000','UserB', 'Restaurant Listing', 'Seq_2'),
    ('2021-01-28 21:13:37.000','UserB', 'Restaurant Listing', 'Seq_3'),
    ('2021-02-16 09:43:27.000','UserA', 'Home', 'Seq_1'),
    ('2021-02-16 09:43:43.000','UserA', 'Write To Us', 'Seq_2'),
    ('2021-02-16 09:44:50.000','UserA', 'My Account', 'Seq_3'),
    ('2021-02-16 09:45:03.000','UserA', 'My Activity', 'Seq_4');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #SD;
with seq_fixed as
(
  select
    UserID,
    DeviceDateTime,
    PageName/*,
    cast(right(PageSequence, charindex('_', reverse(PageSequence)) - 1) as int) as pagesequencefinal*/
  from #App
)
, with_next as
(
  select
    UserID,
    DeviceDateTime,
    PageName,
    lead(PageName) over (partition by UserID/*, DeviceDateTime*/ order by /*UserID,*/ DeviceDateTime ASC) as next_pagename
  from seq_fixed
  /*group by UserID, DeviceDateTime, PageName*/
)
select PageName, next_pagename, count(*) AS No_of_User
into #SD
from with_next
where next_pagename is not null
group by PageName, next_pagename
order by PageName, next_pagename;

SELECT * FROM #SD
```

Comment: Thanks Caius for your prompt reply. I tried your method, but I still failed to capture the second FROM "Home" To "Write To Us". There should be two records of this journey, but I only managed to capture one. Do you know why?

Comment: Er.. One of them says "Write to Use" with a typo? Also, don't forget to dump the `group by UserID, DeviceDateTime, PageName` - you don't need to be grouping at every level.. just group when you do the counts

Comment: Yes, double checked, it was not a typo. Is it because the two records are both from UserA and on different dates? Thorsten Kettner's solution below managed to capture both records.

Comment: If it's not a typo then it's the cause of the problem. Here's a screenshot of what I see when I implement all the advice I gave you: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7C5O.png - look at the bottom, because you group by page name, and you've made a typo on US -> USE, it splits those two highlighted rows into two rows of count 1. In that screenshot the other highlights are the advice I gave: "dump pageseq calc; you don't use it" - top highlight, and "dump the grouping in the middle step" - you've definitely forgotten to do something I advised you to do

Comment: Thanks Caius, let me try again.

Comment: I put a version of your query with commenting out some bits, into the answer - you were very close; the biggest problems were the partitioning was too fine grained and the grouping in the middle was mixing pages up

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Thorsten Kettner: When a user ended on PageX yesterday and starts with Home today, this will count as PageX->Home. I took his advice and try to prevent this from happening with the timestamp column and LAG function. However, it looks super long. Is there a way I can shorten it?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #App
CREATE TABLE #App (
    DeviceDateTime SMALLDATETIME,
    UserID VARCHAR(100),
    PageName VARCHAR(100),
    PageSequence VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #App VALUES
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:00.000','UserA', 'Home', 'Seq_1'),
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:00.000','UserA', 'My Account', 'Seq_2'),
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:07.000','UserA', 'My Activity', 'Seq_3'),
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:07.000','UserA', 'Restaurant Listing', 'Seq_4'),
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:18.000','UserA', 'Restaurant Details Page', 'Seq_5'),
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:31.000','UserA', 'Restaurant Details Page', 'Seq_6'),
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:31.000','UserA', 'Restaurant Booking Confirmation', 'Seq_7'),
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:40.000','UserA', 'Home', 'Seq_8'),
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:45.000','UserA', 'Write To Us', 'Seq_9'),
    ('2021-01-19 16:40:46.000','UserA', 'Home', 'Seq_10'),
    ('2021-01-28 21:11:53.000','UserB', 'Home', 'Seq_1'),
    ('2021-01-28 21:12:01.000','UserB', 'Restaurant Listing', 'Seq_2'),
    ('2021-01-28 21:13:37.000','UserB', 'Restaurant Listing', 'Seq_3'),
    ('2021-02-16 09:43:27.000','UserA', 'Home', 'Seq_1'),
    ('2021-02-16 09:43:43.000','UserA', 'Write To Us', 'Seq_2'),
    ('2021-02-16 09:44:50.000','UserA', 'My Account', 'Seq_3'),
    ('2021-02-16 09:45:03.000','UserA', 'My Activity', 'Seq_4');

    With #App2 as (
select
    DeviceDateTime,
    UserID,
    PageName,
    cast(right(PageSequence, charindex('_', reverse(PageSequence)) - 1) as int) as pagesequencefinal,
    lead(DeviceDateTime) over (partition by UserID order by DeviceDateTime) as next_day,
    cast(lag(DeviceDateTime,1) over (partition by UserID order by DeviceDateTime) as date) as Previous_day,
    CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day, cast(lag(DeviceDateTime,1) over (partition by UserID order by DeviceDateTime) as date), DeviceDateTime) <1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Dayend_flag,
    DATEDIFF(day, cast(lag(DeviceDateTime,1) over (partition by UserID order by DeviceDateTime) as date), DeviceDateTime) as test
  from #App
), #App3 as (
select
    DeviceDateTime,
    UserID,
    PageName,
    pagesequencefinal,
    next_day,
    Previous_day,
    Dayend_flag,
    test,
    SUM(Dayend_flag) OVER (ORDER BY UserID, DeviceDateTime, pagesequencefinal) AS Session_Num
  from #App2
), #App4 as (
select
    UserID,
    PageName,
    lead(PageName) over (partition by Session_Num order by pagesequencefinal) as next_pagename
  from #App3
)
select PageName, next_pagename, count(*) AS No_of_User
from #App4
where next_pagename is not null
group by PageName, next_pagename
order by PageName, next_pagename;
```